# Using Team Foundation Server for a own server

Tags: c#, git, tfs, azure-devops

My team works on SQL database and asp.net in MS Visual Studio 2008. We have own server where our current repository is stored. We use Visual SourceSafe (VSS) 6.0 as the source control. Recently we decided the switch to the latest source control technologies such as Team Foundation Server or GIT.

I was able to create the GIT repository in our server and all team members were able to commit changes in the repository through Visual Studio 2013. But we like the nice GUI of Team foundation server and all of it features like source control explorer, check-out files for edit, managing users group and permission through TFS control panel, etc. It would be convenient for us if we have access to those features.

My question is can we use Visual Studio Team Services by maintaining our central repository in our own server? Or we have to host our source code in Visual Studio Team Services or any other third party repository? We do not want to store our code to any other places other than our own server and still want to use the TFS features.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I used to be in the *keep code in house* until I realized how damn nice it was not having to hire a system admin, consult a licensing specialist, and run patches through a staging server to name a few.

Answer (score 1):

YES, TFS allows you to store your repository on your own private server.  Just install TFS on the server, then Visual Studio will connect to it for each client machine and you can use source control etc.

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer.. Lets see if I understood the process.         I will log in to the remote server machine, install TFS, then each user who has access to remote server will be able to connect to the repository from their own machine... right? The reason I am asking this cause I was able to setup the GIT repository simply by creating the repository to the mapped network drive from my client machine and other team members sitting in another machines still could access the GIT repository as it is in network drive and they have access to that drive.

Comment: TFS is enterprise software. That means that there are a lot of hardware considerations to keep in mind when setting it up. It will be integrated with your Active Directory. This is not a "just install it and it will magically work for everyone" solution. I strongly recommend reading Microsoft's documentation on the installation and administration of TFS before you decide whether to go with an on-prem TFS install or whether to go with Visual Studio Online. VSO is the exact same software, but you don't have to worry about administration.